# Revit rooms and space coordinates in sheet space

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

`<polygon id='b794fee5-9602-4cfa-b738-b72d15fb794c-00056876' points=' -53.29,24.8 -53.29,-11.2 -53.29,-11.2 -33.29,-11.2 -33.29,-11.2 -33.29,4.8 -33.29,4.8 -33.29,12.8 -33.29,12.8 -33.29,24.8 -33.29,24.8 -53.29,24.8' style='fill:blue; stroke:blue; stroke-width:0.5; fill-opacity:0.4;' />`

The coodinates of the svg polygon are from revit space boundaries.

Trying to figure out a way to overlay revit room coordinates on the web browser forge viewer and not able to figure out the coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a supporting image...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These kind of issues are very easy to solve reliably yourself.

Start out simple:

For instance, place a single wall in the model on level zero at a Z height of 0 from X,Y 0,0 to 10,0 in imperial feet.

Examine where it ends up in the Forge viewer.

If all questions are solved, you are done.

If some question remains, place further objects one by one, or make adjustments to your model, one by one, and determine how each modification affects what you see in the viewer.

Don't trust documentation, don't trust others, just find out for yourself and you will be safe forever.